# How to set chapter number as roman in title page but become arabic when stack with section numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I have a problem for my thesis formatting. Can we possibly set chapter number as roman but become continuously arabic when stack with section number like this? (never mind the page numbering, I guess I can handle it...)[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! We need some details about the documentclass etc. that you are using.  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{My chapter}\label{ch:one}
\section{My section}\label{ch:one:se:one}
\subsection{My subsection}\label{ch:one:se:one:sub:one}
We are in chapter~\ref{ch:one}, section~\ref{ch:one:se:one},
subsection~\ref{ch:one:se:one:sub:one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no need to redefine `\thesubsection`

Comment: Nice and simple solution! How did you find out that will work? I mean the commands `\thechapter` and `\Roman` are nowhere documented in the `koma-script` package.